# New RAM within specs installed in a Dell Optiplex 960 but the system doesn’t boot as expected

Tags: memory

I'm having an issue adding additional ram to a Dell Optiplex 960.
I purchased two additional sticks of DDR2 800mhz.

[image]

Here is screenshot of BIOS with system specs

[image]

It has matched specs, size, speed, etc.When I add it to slots 3 and 4, the PC won't boot, just lets out a long beep and will not boot up.

Same happens when I put either stick in slot 4.

When I put either stick in slot 3, the PC acts like its boots, but the monitor output is just a bunch of random colors.

I purchased the RAM from two different sellers on ebay, both of whom claim to have tested it prior to shipping.

I also tried putting the new ram in slots 1 and 2, but same thing, just long beep and nothing.

Also tried 1 stick of new RAM (tried both) in slot 1 by itself, same result.I have a hard time believing I got bad ram from two independent places at the same time.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

[Manual for Optiplex 960](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/desktop-optiplex-960-technical-guidebook-en.pdf)

It supports 8gb total and 8gb per slot.

Original ram is 2x 1GB DDR2 PC2-6400 800mhz DIMS non-ECC
New ram is non-ECC.

Comment: If you remove the memory that is already installed, and install the memory you purchased into those slots, what happens?  Can you supply the information from the labels within the body of your question? The labels cannot be read within the screenshot.

Comment: To quote myself from above - Also tried 1 stick of new RAM (tried both) in slot 1 by itself, same result.I have a hard time believing I got bad ram from two independent places at the same time.

Comment: Can you supply the model information from the original parts.  Are you sure your motherboard supports 2GB modules?

Comment: The motherboard probably doesn't support more than 1GB per slot so the maximum should be 4GB (you're trying to install 6GB!).

Comment: Please see page 12 - https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/desktop-optiplex-960-technical-guidebook-en.pdf It supports up to 8gb total and up to 8gb per slot.

Comment: Update your question with a link to the manual.  You still need to supply the information on the original memory.  The memory you purchased are they ECC or non-ECC?  Update your question with this information.

Comment: Done. My mistake.

Comment: And you're running BIOS A07 from 2010. The latest release was in 2014, version A18. I suggest you update it before anything else.

Comment: @michaelBay Not really sure how to flash it, since the dell utility is a windows exe and I'm running Ubuntu. This is my Zoneminder server, for my PoE security cameras around my house.

Comment: nvm. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln284433/what-is-bios-and-how-to-update-the-bios-on-your-dell-system?lang=en

Comment: Updated to A18 BIOS. Same results.

Comment: Verify the ram Works in another computer.  I understand you may not have another computer but you need to verify the ram Works because as of now you don't know if the ram works.  There is an assumption that it works.  You are probably correct that the ram is good but until you test it and get it working it's still an assumption that could be wrong.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, I do not have another PC that takes DDR2 RAM.

Comment: The only strange thing I see in the user manual is that for 1 GB sticks, you can use 1 or 2 DIMM. with 2 GB sticks you can use 2 or 4 DIMM. This makes me wonder if having 4 DIMM with 1 GB sticks causes an error? I would try both of the new sticks again, and instead of using slot 1 and 2 use slot 1 and 3. Usually the RAM slots are numbered starting with 0. If that's the case use slot 0 and 2.